# How to save pixmap to the JSON document

Tags: json, qt

I need to save and load some data that contains little image to QJsonDocument.

To save pixmap:

```
QPixmap p( ... );
QByteArray res;
QBuffer buffer( &res );
buffer.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly );
p.save( &buffer, "PNG" );
```

Save to QJsonObject:

```
json.insert( "Preview" , res );
```

In result "Preview" data is broken ( from QJsonDocument( json ).toJson() ):

"Preview": "�PNG\r\n\u001a\n"

What I doing wrong? How to save image properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should encode to base64:

```
json.insert( "Preview" , res.toBase64() );
```

This will preserve the data, you will need to decode when you read it in:

```
res = QByteArray::fromBase64(json.take("Preview").toString());
```

Comment: i am getting error cannot convert argument 2 from QByteArray to QJsonValue